# Why is my rating not increasing on lichess.org?

Tags: rating, lichess

I played some rated games and don't understand why my score doesn't go up. Usually, my score either goes up or goes down, depending on if I win or not. This time, it didn't even change. It is weird.

Comment: Can you link your profile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have accepted an unrated friendly match. Friendly games don't affect your rating on lichess.